# Peripheral mode is off

Tags: bluetooth-pairing, peripherals

I can't pair my activity tracker (Mi band 2, xiaomi) with my tablet/app (Android 5.1 ).

According to BLE Scanner app: no nearby BLE devices, 'peripheral mode not supported in your device'

When I open the app (Mi fit) : discoverable is off

How do I fix it?

Note: I got the tablet for free and there's no name or brand, only "rockship 791"

Answer (score 0):

Does Mi fit connect to the Mi band? If not try to install an older version, I found that while trying to configure smart unlock, as with newer version of the app I could not find the device on an HTC one M8